# Connect three sentences and make a shorter sentence

Tags: coordination, lists

Suppose three sentences:

1- I have eaten lunch.

2- I have slept.

3- I have come here.

Is it right to say: 'I have eaten lunch, slept and come here.'?

What about 'I have eaten lunch, have slept and have come here.'?

Comment: Only the first sentence sounds idiomatic without much context; combining the sentences sounds peculiar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences you suggested are correct, but the first is probably more "correct", as the repetition of the haves in the second is unnecessary because the haves are understood from the first action (e.g. have eaten lunch).

Comment: ***Why*** is it unnecessary?

Comment: because it is understood from the first action (e.g. have eaten lunch)

Comment: Yes, add that to your answer. Make it complete and comprehensive.